# Jooq postgre insert error with play2.5 scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, jooq

I'm using jooq in an app with play2.5 and scala

When I'm inserting a simple query the driver prepares a query with ` around table and field names and postgres responds with an error, how can I overcome this, there is probably a driver parameter to set this behavior?

I'm using

the sbt config

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  evolutions,
  filters,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0-RC1" % Test,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1003-jdbc4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.7.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.7.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.7.0",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap" % "1.1-P25-B3",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
)
```

the error:

```
[debug] 2017-03-12 11:18:52,042 o.j.t.LoggerListener - Executing query          : insert into `public`.`user_account` (`nickname`, `email`, `password`, `role`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
[debug] 2017-03-12 11:18:52,043 o.j.t.LoggerListener - -> with bind values      : insert into `public`.`user_account` (`nickname`, `email`, `password`, `role`) values ('', 'simon.cigoj@gmail.com', 'nomis05', 'ROLE_USER')
[error] 2017-03-12 11:18:52,139 o.j.StatementLogger - insert into `public`.`user_account` (`nickname`, `email`, `password`, `role`) values ('', 'aaa@mail.com', 'kjhkh', 'ROLE_USER');
throws exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
  Position: 13
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
  Position: 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you did not set the correct `SQLDialect`, like

```
SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_5
```

https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.8.x/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html

Comment: true, I have just found it myself, I have switched from mariadb to postgre an forgot to set the dialog